# Color quantization with N out of M predefined colors

Tags: java, image-processing, color-palette

I am having a slightly odd problem trying to quantize and dither an RGB image. Ideally, I should be able to implement a suitable algorithm in Java or use a Java library, but references to implementations in other languages may be helpful as well.

The following is given as input:

- `image`: 24-bit RGB bitmap
- `palette`: a list of colors defined with their RGB values
- `max_cols`: the maximum number of colours to be used in the output image

It is perhaps important, that both the size of the palette as well as the maximum number of allowed colours is not necessarily a power of 2 and may be greater than 255.

So, the goal is to take the `image`, select up to `max_cols` colours from the provided `palette` and output an image using only the picked colours and rendered using some kind of error-diffusion dithering. Which dithering algorithm to use is not that important, but it should be an error-diffusion variant (e.g. Floyd-Steinberg) and not simple halftone or ordered dithering.

Performance is not particularly important and the size of the expected data input is relatively small. The images would rarely be larger than 500x500 pixel, the provided palette may contain some 3-400 colours and the number of colours will usually be limited to less than 100. It is also safe to assume that the palette contains a wide selection of colours, covering variations of both hue, saturation and brightness.

The palette selection and dithering used by [scolorq](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~dcoetzee/downloads/scolorq/) would be ideal, but it does not seem easy to adapt the algorithm to select colours from an already defined palette instead of arbitrary colours.

To be more precise, the problem where I am stuck is the selection of suitable colours from the provided palette. Assume that I e.g. use scolorq to create a palette with N colours and later replace the colours defined by scolorq with the closest colours from the provided palette, and then use these colours combined with error-diffused dithering. This will produce a result at least similar to the input image, but due to the unpredictable hues of the selected colours, the output image may get a strong, undesired colour cast. E.g. when using a grey-scale input image and a palette with only few neutral gray tones, but a great range of brown tones (or more generally, many colours with the same hue, low saturation and a great variation in the brightness), my colour selection algorithm seem to prefer these colours above the neutral greys since the brown tones are at least mathematically closer to the desired colour than the greys. The same problem remains even if I convert the RGB values to HSB and use different weights for the H, S and B channels when trying to find the nearest available colour.

Any suggestions how to implement this properly, or even better a library I can use to perform the task?

Since Xabster asked, I can also explain the goal with this excercise, although it has nothing to do with how the actual problem can be solved. The target for the output image is an embroidery or tapestry pattern. In the most simplest case, each pixel in the output image corresponds to a stitch made on some kind of carrier fabric. The palette corresponds to the available yarns, which usually come in several hundred colours. For practical reasons, it is however necessary to limit the number of colours used in the actual work. Googling for gobelin embroideries will give several examples.

And to clarify where the problem exactly lies... The solution can indeed be split into two separate steps:

- selecting the optimal subset of the original palette
- using the subset to render the output image

Here, the first step is the actual problem. If the palette selection works properly, I could simply use the selected colours and e.g. Floyd-Steinberg dithering to produce a reasonable result (which is rather trivial to implement).

If I understand the implementation of scolorq correctly, scolorq however combines these two steps, using knowledge of the dithering algorithm in the palette selection to create an even better result. That would of course be a preferred solution, but the algorithms used in scolorq work slightly beyond my mathematical knowledge.

Comment: I'll try to find an answer, is it ok if I use javascript (with `processing.js`) to help solving your problem ?

Comment: I am not familiar with processing.js. If using processing.js means that I have to run the software in a web page and the resulting image will only be rendered in a browser without the ability to save it as an image file, that won't really help me.

Comment: Actually you can save a file from an rendered view of a canvas, I'll made a jsfiddle, I do not guarantee a success though !

Comment: I think you can use an [OrderedDitherDescriptor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/operator/OrderedDitherDescriptor.html).

Comment: @Elliot: Unless I miss something, OrdererdDitherDescriptor will only do the dithering and not the palette selection (the problem where I'm actually stuck). If I have found a reasonable way to select the palette to use, implementing dithering is rather trivial without using JAI.

Comment: So, your issue is that the mathematical distance between two colors does not correspond to the humanly perceived color distance? If so, here is some work on subjective color differences: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference

Comment: @Xabster: That is at least one part of the problem. The main issue however, is how to select an optimal subset of the available palette, so that the output image can be rendered as close to the input image as possible. As I tried to explain in the question, simply selecting palette entries close to the colours used in the image does not work particularly well.

Comment: Alright, so it's both a problem of selecting a subset of the whole palette of available colors AND determining which color to use for each substitution. What is the goal of selecting a subset of the palette? Compression?

Comment: @Xabster: That was too much for a comment, but I've edited my question trying to answer your issues there.

Comment: There are max_cols! possibilities, to that looks like a hard problem to me

Comment: @RobAu: I already considered a brute force attack as well, but the run time would not be acceptable, even if I don't have very strict performance requirements. There are even more possibilities than max_cols!. Selecting N of M colours should give M!/(N!*(M-N)!) possibilities if I remember correctly.

Comment: You havn't seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940188/how-to-convert-a-24-bit-png-to-3-bit-png-using-floydsteinberg-dithering) one, have you?

Comment: @Hannes: No, I haven't seen that question, but it does not solve my problem either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**OVERVIEW**

This is a possible approach to the problem:

1) Each color from the input pixels is mapped to the closest color from the input color palette.

2) If the resulting palette is greater than the allowed maximum number of colors, the palette gets reduced to the maximum allowed number, by removing the colors, that are most similar with each other from the computed palette (I did choose the nearest distance for removal, so the resulting image remains high in contrast).

3) If the resulting palette is smaller than the allowed maximum number of colors, it gets filled with the most similar colors from the remaining colors of the input palette until the allowed number of colors is reached. This is done in the hope, that the dithering algorithm could make use of these colors during dithering. Note though that I didn't see much difference between filling or not filling the palette for the Floyd-Steinberg algorithm...

4) As a last step the input pixels get dithered with the computed palette.

---

**IMPLEMENTATION**

Below is an implementation of this approach.

If you want to run the source code, you will need this class: [ImageFrame.java](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Aframethatdisplaysanimage.htm). You can set the input image as the only program argument, all other parameters must be set in the main method. The used Floyd-Steinberg algorithm is from [Floyd-Steinberg dithering](http://en.literateprograms.org/Floyd-Steinberg_dithering_%28Java%29?oldid=12476).

One can choose between 3 different reduction strategies for the palette reduction algorithm:

1) `ORIGINAL_COLORS`: This algorithm tries to stay as true to the input pixel colors as possible by searching for the two colors in the palette, that have the least distance. From these two colors it removes the one with the fewest mappings to pixels in the input map.

2) `BETTER_CONTRAST`: Works like `ORIGINAL_COLORS`, with the difference, that from the two colors it removes the one with the lowest average distance to the rest of the palette.

3) `AVERAGE_DISTANCE`: This algorithm always removes the colors with the lowest average distance from the pool. This setting can especially improve the quality of the resulting image for grayscale palettes.

Here is the complete code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.PixelGrabber;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class Quantize {

public static class RGBTriple {
    public final int[] channels;
    public RGBTriple() { channels = new int[3]; }

    public RGBTriple(int color) { 
        int r = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int g = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int b = (color >> 0) & 0xFF;
        channels = new int[]{(int)r, (int)g, (int)b};
    }
    public RGBTriple(int R, int G, int B)
    { channels = new int[]{(int)R, (int)G, (int)B}; }
}

/* The authors of this work have released all rights to it and placed it
in the public domain under the Creative Commons CC0 1.0 waiver
(http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/).

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

Retrieved from: http://en.literateprograms.org/Floyd-Steinberg_dithering_(Java)?oldid=12476
 */
public static class FloydSteinbergDither
{
    private static int plus_truncate_uchar(int a, int b) {
        if ((a & 0xff) + b < 0)
            return 0;
        else if ((a & 0xff) + b > 255)
            return (int)255;
        else
            return (int)(a + b);
    }


    private static int findNearestColor(RGBTriple color, RGBTriple[] palette) {
        int minDistanceSquared = 255*255 + 255*255 + 255*255 + 1;
        int bestIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < palette.length; i++) {
            int Rdiff = (color.channels[0] & 0xff) - (palette[i].channels[0] & 0xff);
            int Gdiff = (color.channels[1] & 0xff) - (palette[i].channels[1] & 0xff);
            int Bdiff = (color.channels[2] & 0xff) - (palette[i].channels[2] & 0xff);
            int distanceSquared = Rdiff*Rdiff + Gdiff*Gdiff + Bdiff*Bdiff;
            if (distanceSquared < minDistanceSquared) {
                minDistanceSquared = distanceSquared;
                bestIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return bestIndex;
    }

    public static int[][] floydSteinbergDither(RGBTriple[][] image, RGBTriple[] palette)
    {
        int[][] result = new int[image.length][image[0].length];

        for (int y = 0; y < image.length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < image[y].length; x++) {
                RGBTriple currentPixel = image[y][x];
                int index = findNearestColor(currentPixel, palette);
                result[y][x] = index;

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    int error = (currentPixel.channels[i] & 0xff) - (palette[index].channels[i] & 0xff);
                    if (x + 1 < image[0].length) {
                        image[y+0][x+1].channels[i] =
                                plus_truncate_uchar(image[y+0][x+1].channels[i], (error*7) >> 4);
                    }
                    if (y + 1 < image.length) {
                        if (x - 1 > 0) {
                            image[y+1][x-1].channels[i] =
                                    plus_truncate_uchar(image[y+1][x-1].channels[i], (error*3) >> 4);
                        }
                        image[y+1][x+0].channels[i] =
                                plus_truncate_uchar(image[y+1][x+0].channels[i], (error*5) >> 4);
                        if (x + 1 < image[0].length) {
                            image[y+1][x+1].channels[i] =
                                    plus_truncate_uchar(image[y+1][x+1].channels[i], (error*1) >> 4);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void generateDither(int[] pixels, int[] p, int w, int h){
        RGBTriple[] palette = new RGBTriple[p.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < palette.length; i++) {
            int color = p[i];
            palette[i] = new RGBTriple(color);
        }
        RGBTriple[][] image = new RGBTriple[w][h];
        for (int x = w; x-- > 0; ) {
            for (int y = h; y-- > 0; ) {
                int index = y * w + x;
                int color = pixels[index];
                image[x][y] = new RGBTriple(color);
            }
        }

        int[][] result = floydSteinbergDither(image, palette);
        convert(result, pixels, p, w, h);

    }

    public static void convert(int[][] result, int[] pixels, int[] p, int w, int h){
        for (int x = w; x-- > 0; ) {
            for (int y = h; y-- > 0; ) {
                int index = y * w + x;
                int index2 = result[x][y];
                pixels[index] = p[index2];
            }
        }
    }
}

private static class PaletteColor{
    final int color;
    public PaletteColor(int color) {
        super();
        this.color = color;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + color;
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        PaletteColor other = (PaletteColor) obj;
        if (color != other.color)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();
}


public static int[] getPixels(Image image) throws IOException {
    int w = image.getWidth(null);
    int h = image.getHeight(null);        
    int pix[] = new int[w * h];
    PixelGrabber grabber = new PixelGrabber(image, 0, 0, w, h, pix, 0, w);

    try {
        if (grabber.grabPixels() != true) {
            throw new IOException("Grabber returned false: " +
                    grabber.status());
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return pix;
}

/**
 * Returns the color distance between color1 and color2
 */
public static float getPixelDistance(PaletteColor color1, PaletteColor color2){
    int c1 = color1.color;
    int r1 = (c1 >> 16) & 0xFF;
    int g1 = (c1 >> 8) & 0xFF;
    int b1 = (c1 >> 0) & 0xFF;
    int c2 = color2.color;
    int r2 = (c2 >> 16) & 0xFF;
    int g2 = (c2 >> 8) & 0xFF;
    int b2 = (c2 >> 0) & 0xFF;
    return (float) getPixelDistance(r1, g1, b1, r2, g2, b2);
}

public static double getPixelDistance(int r1, int g1, int b1, int r2, int g2, int b2){
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r2 - r1, 2) + Math.pow(g2 - g1, 2) + Math.pow(b2 - b1, 2));
}

/**
 * Fills the given fillColors palette with the nearest colors from the given colors palette until
 * it has the given max_cols size.
 */
public static void fillPalette(List<PaletteColor> fillColors, List<PaletteColor> colors, int max_cols){
    while (fillColors.size() < max_cols) {
        int index = -1;
        float minDistance = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < fillColors.size(); i++) {
            PaletteColor color1 = colors.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < colors.size(); j++) {
                PaletteColor color2 = colors.get(j);
                if (color1 == color2) {
                    continue;
                }
                float distance = getPixelDistance(color1, color2);
                if (index == -1 || distance < minDistance) {
                    index = j;
                    minDistance = distance;
                }
            }
        }
        PaletteColor color = colors.get(index);
        fillColors.add(color);
    }
}

public static void reducePaletteByAverageDistance(List<PaletteColor> colors, int max_cols, ReductionStrategy reductionStrategy){
    while (colors.size() > max_cols) {
        int index = -1;
        float minDistance = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.size(); i++) {
            PaletteColor color1 = colors.get(i);
            float averageDistance = 0;
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < colors.size(); j++) {
                PaletteColor color2 = colors.get(j);
                if (color1 == color2) {
                    continue;
                }
                averageDistance += getPixelDistance(color1, color2);
                count++;
            }
            averageDistance/=count;
            if (minDistance == -1 || averageDistance < minDistance) {
                minDistance = averageDistance;
                index = i;
            }
        }
        PaletteColor removed = colors.remove(index);
        // find the color with the least distance:
        PaletteColor best = null;
        minDistance = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.size(); i++) {
            PaletteColor c = colors.get(i);
            float distance = getPixelDistance(c, removed);
            if (best == null || distance < minDistance) {
                best = c;
                minDistance = distance;
            }
        }
        best.indices.addAll(removed.indices);

    }
}
/**
 * Reduces the given color palette until it has the given max_cols size.
 * The colors that are closest in distance to other colors in the palette
 * get removed first.
 */
public static void reducePalette(List<PaletteColor> colors, int max_cols, ReductionStrategy reductionStrategy){
    if (reductionStrategy == ReductionStrategy.AVERAGE_DISTANCE) {
        reducePaletteByAverageDistance(colors, max_cols, reductionStrategy);
        return;
    }
    while (colors.size() > max_cols) {
        int index1 = -1;
        int index2 = -1;
        float minDistance = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.size(); i++) {
            PaletteColor color1 = colors.get(i);
            for (int j = i+1; j < colors.size(); j++) {
                PaletteColor color2 = colors.get(j);
                if (color1 == color2) {
                    continue;
                }
                float distance = getPixelDistance(color1, color2);
                if (index1 == -1 || distance < minDistance) {
                    index1 = i;
                    index2 = j;
                    minDistance = distance;
                }
            }
        }
        PaletteColor color1 = colors.get(index1);
        PaletteColor color2 = colors.get(index2);

        switch (reductionStrategy) {
            case BETTER_CONTRAST:
                // remove the color with the lower average distance to the other palette colors
                int count = 0;
                float distance1 = 0;
                float distance2 = 0;
                for (PaletteColor c : colors) {
                    if (c != color1 && c != color2) {
                        count++;
                        distance1 += getPixelDistance(color1, c);
                        distance2 += getPixelDistance(color2, c);
                    }
                }
                if (count != 0 && distance1 != distance2) {
                    distance1 /= (float)count;
                    distance2 /= (float)count;
                    if (distance1 < distance2) {
                        // remove color 1;
                        colors.remove(index1);
                        color2.indices.addAll(color1.indices);
                    } else{
                        // remove color 2;
                        colors.remove(index2);
                        color1.indices.addAll(color2.indices);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                //$FALL-THROUGH$
            default:
                // remove the color with viewer mappings to the input pixels
                if (color1.indices.size() < color2.indices.size()) {
                    // remove color 1;
                    colors.remove(index1);
                    color2.indices.addAll(color1.indices);
                } else{
                    // remove color 2;
                    colors.remove(index2);
                    color1.indices.addAll(color2.indices);
                }
                break;
        }

    }
}

/**
 * Creates an initial color palette from the given pixels and the given palette by
 * selecting the colors with the nearest distance to the given pixels.
 * This method also stores the indices of the corresponding pixels inside the
 * returned PaletteColor instances.
 */
public static List<PaletteColor> createInitialPalette(int pixels[], int[] palette){
    Map<Integer, Integer> used = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<PaletteColor> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0, l = pixels.length; i < l; i++) {
        double bestDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        int bestIndex = -1;

        int pixel = pixels[i];
        int r1 = (pixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int g1 = (pixel >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int b1 = (pixel >> 0) & 0xFF;
        for (int k = 0; k < palette.length; k++) {
            int pixel2 = palette[k];
            int r2 = (pixel2 >> 16) & 0xFF;
            int g2 = (pixel2 >> 8) & 0xFF;
            int b2 = (pixel2 >> 0) & 0xFF;
            double dist = getPixelDistance(r1, g1, b1, r2, g2, b2);
            if (dist < bestDistance) {
                bestDistance = dist;
                bestIndex = k;
            }
        }

        Integer index = used.get(bestIndex);
        PaletteColor c;
        if (index == null) {
            index = result.size();
            c = new PaletteColor(palette[bestIndex]);
            result.add(c);
            used.put(bestIndex, index);
        } else{
            c = result.get(index);
        }
        c.indices.add(i);
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Creates a simple random color palette
 */
public static int[] createRandomColorPalette(int num_colors){
    Random random = new Random(101);

    int count = 0;
    int[] result = new int[num_colors];
    float add = 360f / (float)num_colors;
    for(float i = 0; i < 360f && count < num_colors; i += add) {
        float hue = i;
        float saturation = 90 +random.nextFloat() * 10;
        float brightness = 50 + random.nextFloat() * 10;
        result[count++] = Color.HSBtoRGB(hue, saturation, brightness);
    }
    return result;
}

public static int[] createGrayScalePalette(int count){
    float[] grays = new float[count];
    float step = 1f/(float)count;
    grays[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < count-1; i++) {
        grays[i]=i*step;
    }
    grays[count-1]=1;
    return createGrayScalePalette(grays);
}

/**
 * Returns a grayscale palette based on the given shades of gray
 */
public static int[] createGrayScalePalette(float[] grays){
    int[] result = new int[grays.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        float f = grays[i];
        result[i] = Color.HSBtoRGB(0, 0, f);
    }
    return result;
}


private static int[] createResultingImage(int[] pixels,List<PaletteColor> paletteColors, boolean dither, int w, int h) {
    int[] palette = new int[paletteColors.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < palette.length; i++) {
        palette[i] = paletteColors.get(i).color;
    }
    if (!dither) {
        for (PaletteColor c : paletteColors) {
            for (int i : c.indices) {
                pixels[i] = c.color;
            }
        }
    } else{
        FloydSteinbergDither.generateDither(pixels, palette, w, h);
    }
    return palette;
}

public static int[] quantize(int[] pixels, int widht, int heigth, int[] colorPalette, int max_cols, boolean dither, ReductionStrategy reductionStrategy) {

    // create the initial palette by finding the best match colors from the given color palette
    List<PaletteColor> paletteColors = createInitialPalette(pixels, colorPalette);

    // reduce the palette size to the given number of maximum colors
    reducePalette(paletteColors, max_cols, reductionStrategy);
    assert paletteColors.size() <= max_cols;

    if (paletteColors.size() < max_cols) {
        // fill the palette with the nearest remaining colors
        List<PaletteColor> remainingColors = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<PaletteColor> used = new HashSet<>(paletteColors);
        for (int i = 0; i < colorPalette.length; i++) {
            int color = colorPalette[i];
            PaletteColor c = new PaletteColor(color);
            if (!used.contains(c)) {
                remainingColors.add(c);
            }
        }
        fillPalette(paletteColors, remainingColors, max_cols);
    }
    assert paletteColors.size() == max_cols;

    // create the resulting image
    return createResultingImage(pixels,paletteColors, dither, widht, heigth);

}   

static enum ReductionStrategy{
    ORIGINAL_COLORS,
    BETTER_CONTRAST,
    AVERAGE_DISTANCE,
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    // input parameters
    String imageFileName = args[0];
    File file = new File(imageFileName);

    boolean dither = true;
    int colorPaletteSize = 80;
    int max_cols = 3;
    max_cols =  Math.min(max_cols, colorPaletteSize);

    // create some random color palette
    //  int[] colorPalette = createRandomColorPalette(colorPaletteSize);
    int[] colorPalette = createGrayScalePalette(20);

    ReductionStrategy reductionStrategy = ReductionStrategy.AVERAGE_DISTANCE;

    // show the original image inside a frame
    ImageFrame original = new ImageFrame();
    original.setImage(file);
    original.setTitle("Original Image");
    original.setLocation(0, 0);

    Image image = original.getImage();
    int width = image.getWidth(null);
    int heigth = image.getHeight(null);
    int pixels[] = getPixels(image);
    int[] palette = quantize(pixels, width, heigth, colorPalette, max_cols, dither, reductionStrategy);

    // show the reduced image in another frame
    ImageFrame reduced = new ImageFrame();
    reduced.setImage(width, heigth, pixels);
    reduced.setTitle("Quantized Image (" + palette.length + " colors, dither: " + dither + ")");
    reduced.setLocation(100, 100);

}
}
```

---

**POSSIBLE IMPROVEMENTS**

1) The used Floyd-Steinberg algorithm does currently only work for palettes with a maximum size of  **256** colors. I guess this could be fixed easily, but since the used FloydSteinbergDither class requires quite a lot of conversions at the moment, it would certainly be better to implement the algorithm from scratch so it fits the color model that is used in the end.

2) I believe using another dithering algorithm like [scolorq](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~dcoetzee/downloads/scolorq/) would perhaps be better. On the "To Do List" at the end of their homepage they write:

> [TODO:] The ability to fix some colors to a predetermined set (supported by the algorithm but not the current implementation)

So it seems using a fixed palette should be possible for the algorithm. The  Photoshop/Gimp plugin [Ximagic](http://www.ximagic.com/) seems to implement this functionality using scolorq. From their homepage:

> Ximagic Quantizer is a Photoshop plugin for image color quantization (color reduction) & dithering.
>   Provides: **Predefined palette quantization**

3) The algorithm to fill the palette could perhaps be improved - e.g. by filling the palette with colors depending on their average distance (like in the reduction algorithm). But this should be tested depending on the finally used dithering algorithm.

Comment: Your first point is correct. If I could use the entire palette, I would get a good result using the process you describe. Your second point is however wrong. Even if I use the result of the first step as input in a "normal" quantization and dithering process, e.g. scolorq, the output is not guaranteed to use only colours in the original palette. scolorq (and quantization algorithms based on clustering for that matter) will not use an exact subset of the colours in the input image, but may just as well use other colours if they are better fit to render the image.

Comment: This looks very promising. I'll make some further tests and accept this answer if I don't find any issues.

Answer (score 0):

### First of all I'd like to insist on the fact that **this is no advanced distance color computation.**

So far I assumed the first palette is one you either **configured** or **precalculated from an image**.

Here, I only configured it and focused on the subpalette extraction problem. I did not use an algorithm, it's highly probable that **it may not be the best**.

1. Store an image into a canvas 2d context which will serve as a buffer, I'll refer to it as `ctxHidden`
2. Store pixels data of `ctxHidden` into a variable called `img`
3. Loop through entire `img` with function `constraintImageData(img, palette)` which accepts as argument `img` and the `palette` to transform current `img` pixels to given colors with the help of the distance function `nearestColor(palette, r, g, b, a)`. Note that this function returns a `witness`, which basically counts how many times each colors of the palette being used **at least once**. My example also applies a Floyd-Steinberg dithering, even though you  mentionned it was not a problem.
4. Use the witness to sort descending by colors apparition frequency (from the palette)
5. Extract these colors from the initial palette to get a subpalette according to `maxColors` (or `max_colors`)
6. Draw the image with the final subpalette, from `ctxHidden` original data.

---

### You must expect your final image to give you squishy results if `maxColors` is too low or if your original palette is too distant from the original image colors.

---

[I did a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eN8Qn/20/) with `processing.js`, and it is clearly not *necessary* here but I started using it so I left it as is.

### **Now here is what the code looks like (the second canvas is the result, applying the final subpalette with a delay of 3 seconds)**

```
var image = document.getElementById('original'),
    palettePanel = document.getElementById('palette'),
    subPalettePanel = document.getElementById('subpalette'),
    canvas = document.getElementById('main'),
    maxColors = 12,
    palette = [
         0x7F8FB1FF,
         0x000000FF,
         0x404c00FF,
         0xe46501FF,
         0x722640FF,
         0x40337fFF,
         0x666666FF,
         0x0e5940FF,
         0x1bcb01FF,
         0xbfcc80FF,
         0x333333FF,
         0x0033CCFF,
         0x66CCFFFF,
         0xFF6600FF,
         0x000033FF,
         0xFFCC00FF,
         0xAA0033FF,
         0xFF00FFFF,
         0x00FFFFFF,
         0x123456FF
     ],
      nearestColor = function (palette, r, g, b, a) {
            var rr, gg, bb, aa, color, closest,
                distr, distg, distb, dista,
                dist,
                minDist = Infinity;
            for (var i =  0; i < l; i++) {
                color = palette[i];
                rr = palette[i] >> 24 & 0xFF;
                gg = palette[i] >> 16 & 0xFF;
                bb = palette[i] >> 8  & 0xFF;
                aa = palette[i]       & 0xFF;

                if (closest === undefined) {
                    closest = color;
                }

                // compute abs value
                distr = Math.abs(rr - r);
                distg = Math.abs(gg - g);
                distb = Math.abs(bb - b);
                dista = Math.abs(aa - a);
                dist = (distr + distg + distb + dista * .5) / 3.5;

                if (dist < minDist) {
                    closest = color;
                    minDist = dist;
                }
            }

            return closest; 
     },
     subpalette = [],
     i, l = palette.length,
     r, g, b, a,
     img,
     size = 5,
     cols = palettePanel.width / size,
     drawPalette = function (p, palette) {
            var i, l = palette.length;

            p.setup = function () {
            p.size(50,50);
            p.background(255);
            p.noStroke();

            for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {

                r = palette[i] >> 24 & 0xFF;
                g = palette[i] >> 16 & 0xFF;
                b = palette[i] >> 8  & 0xFF;
                a = palette[i]       & 0xFF;

                p.fill(r,g,b,a);
                p.rect (i%cols*size, ~~(i/cols)*size, size, size);
            }
        }
     },
        constraintImageDataToPalette = function (img, palette) {
            var i, l, x, y, index,
                pixel, x, y,
                right, bottom, bottomLeft, bottomRight,
                color,
                r, g, b, a, i, l,
                pr, pg, pb, pa,
                rErrorBase,
                gErrorBase,
                bErrorBase,
                aErrorBase,
                index,
                w = img.width,
                w4 = w*4,
                h = img.height,
                witness = {};

            for (i = 0, l = w*h*4; i < l; i += 4) {
                x = (i%w);
                y = ~~(i/w);
                index = x + y*w;
                right = index + 4,
                bottomLeft = index - 4 + w4,
                bottom = index + w4,
                bottomRight = index + w4 + 4,
                pixel = img.data;

                r = pixel[index];
                g = pixel[index+1];
                b = pixel[index+2];
                a = pixel[index+3];

                color = nearestColor(palette, r,g,b,a);
                witness[color] = (witness[color] || 0) + 1;

                // explode channels
                pr = color >> 24 & 0xFF;
                pg = color >> 16 & 0xFF;
                pb = color >> 8  & 0xFF;
                pa = color       & 0xFF;

                // set new color
                pixel[index]   = pr;
                pixel[index+1] = pg;
                pixel[index+2] = pb;
                pixel[index+3] = pa;

                // calculate error
                rErrorBase = (r - pr);
                gErrorBase = (g - pg);
                bErrorBase = (b - pb);
                aErrorBase = (a - pa);

                ///*
                // diffuse error right 7/16 = 0.4375
                pixel[right]   += 0.4375 * rErrorBase;
                pixel[right+1] += 0.4375 * gErrorBase;
                pixel[right+2] += 0.4375 * bErrorBase;
                pixel[right+3] += 0.4375 * aErrorBase;

                // diffuse error bottom-left 3/16 = 0.1875
                pixel[bottomLeft]   += 0.1875 * rErrorBase;
                pixel[bottomLeft+1] += 0.1875 * gErrorBase;
                pixel[bottomLeft+2] += 0.1875 * bErrorBase;
                pixel[bottomLeft+3] += 0.1875 * aErrorBase;

                // diffuse error bottom 5/16 = 0.3125
                pixel[bottom]   += 0.3125 * rErrorBase;
                pixel[bottom+1] += 0.3125 * gErrorBase;
                pixel[bottom+2] += 0.3125 * bErrorBase;
                pixel[bottom+3] += 0.3125 * aErrorBase;

                //diffuse error bottom-right 1/16 = 0.0625
                pixel[bottomRight]   += 0.0625 * rErrorBase;
                pixel[bottomRight+1] += 0.0625 * gErrorBase;
                pixel[bottomRight+2] += 0.0625 * bErrorBase;
                pixel[bottomRight+3] += 0.0625 * aErrorBase;
                //*/
            }
            return witness;
        };

new Processing(palettePanel, function (p) { drawPalette(p, palette); });

image.onload = function () {
        var l = palette.length;
    new Processing(canvas, function (p) {

        // argb 24 bits colors
        p.setup = function () {
            p.size(300, 200);
            p.background(0);
            p.noStroke();

            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
                ctxHidden = document.getElementById('buffer').getContext('2d'),
                img, log = [],
                witness = {};

            ctxHidden.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
            img = ctxHidden.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            // constraint colors to largest palette
            witness = constraintImageDataToPalette(img, palette);
            // show which colors have been picked from the panel
            new Processing(subPalettePanel, function (p) { drawPalette(p, Object.keys(witness)); });
            ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0);

            var colorsWeights = [];

            for (var key in witness) {
                colorsWeights.push([+key, witness[key]]);
            }

            // sort descending colors by most presents ones
            colorsWeights.sort(function (a, b) {
                return b[1] - a[1];
            });

            // get the max_colors first of the colors picked to ensure a higher probability of getting a good color
            subpalette = colorsWeights
                .slice(0, maxColors)
                .map(function (colorValueCount) {
                    // return the actual color code
                    return colorValueCount[0];
            });

            // reset image we previously modified
            img = ctxHidden.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            // this time constraint with new subpalette
            constraintImageDataToPalette(img, subpalette);

            // wait 3 seconds to apply new palette and show exactly how it changed
            setTimeout(function () {
                new Processing(subPalettePanel, function (p) { drawPalette(p, subpalette); });
                ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
            }, 3000);
        };
    });
};
```

**NOTE**: I have no experience in java image computation, so I used javascript instead. I tried to comment my code, if you have any question about it I'll answer and explain it.

Comment: This approach is basically the same as in Gabriel Archanjo's answer, so the issues I commented on his answer apply to this solution as well.

Comment: What if you first apply the dithering, then calculate the most frequents colors from the resulting pixels and finally apply the new palette, without dithering another time ?

Comment: Please try it with a white-black gradient, a palette with four gray tones ranging from white to black and then reduce the number of colours to two. It won't work.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I think I may have answered a slightly different question. jarnbjo pointed out something that may be wrong with my solution, and I realized I misunderstood the question. I'm leaving my answer here for posterity, though.

I may have a solution to this in Matlab. To find the closest color, I used the weights given by Albert Renshaw in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720528/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-finding-the-closest-color-in-an-array-to-another). I used the HSV colorspace, but all inputs to the code were in standard RGB. Greyscale iamges were converted to 3-channel greyscale images.

To select the best colors to use, I seeded kmeans with the test sample palette and then reset the centroids to be the values they were closest to in the sample pallet.

```
function imo = recolor(im,new_colors,max_colors)

% Convert to HSV
im2 = rgb2hsv(im);
new_colors = rgb2hsv(new_colors);

% Get number of colors in palette
num_colors = uint8(size(new_colors,1));

% Reshape image so every row is a diferent pixel, and every column a channel
% this is necessary for kmeans in Matlab
im2 = reshape(im2, size(im,1)*size(im,2),size(im,3));

% Seed kmeans with sample pallet, drop empty clusters
[IDX, C] = kmeans(im2,max_colors,'emptyaction','drop');

% For each pixel, IDX tells which cluster in C it corresponds to
% C contains the centroids of each cluster


% Because centroids are adjusted from seeds, we need to select which original color
% in the palette it corresponds to. We cannot be sure that the centroids in C correspond
% to their seed values
% Note that Matlab starts indexing at 1 instead of 0
for i=1:size(C,1)
    H = C(i,1);
    S = C(i,2);
    V = C(i,3);
    bdel = 100;
    % Find which color in the new_colors palette is closest
    for j=1:size(new_colors,1)
        H2 = new_colors(j,1);
        S2 = new_colors(j,2);
        V2 = new_colors(j,3);
        dH = (H2-H)^2*0.475;
        dS = (S2-S)^2*0.2875;
        dV = (V2-V)^2*0.2375;
        del = sqrt(dH+dS+dV);
        if isnan(del)
            continue
        end
        % update if the new delta is lower than the best
        if del<bdel
            bdel = del;
            C(i,:) = new_colors(j,:);
        end
    end
end

% Update the colors, this is equal to the following
% for i=1:length(imo)
%    imo(i,:) = C(IDX(i),:) 
imo = C(IDX,:);

% put it back in its original shape
imo = reshape(imo, size(im));

imo = hsv2rgb(imo);

imshow(imo);
```

The problem with it right now as I have it written is that it is very slow for color images (Lenna took several minutes).

Is this along the lines of what you are looking for?

[Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gk6U.jpg).

If you don't understand all the Matlab notation, let me know.

Comment: Well, to be honest I have absolutely no knowledge about Matlab notation, but I think I should be able to understand it. What I'm missing however, is where you define max_cols, that is the number of colours to be selected from the palette?

Comment: Oh right. That my be a problem with my solution. When I wrote it I was using max_colors = colors_in_palette. I think it may still work, though. We just won't seed kmeans anymore. This should be fine since we have can have fewer than max_colors in the final product. Add max_colors to the arguments list, and change the line "[IDX, C] = kmeans(im2,num_colors,'start',new_colors,'emptyaction','drop');" to [IDX, C] = kmeans(im2,max_colors,'emptyaction','drop');

It should work now. I retested my code with the change, and it sill looks ok.

Comment: You'll probably want to make sure that the kmeans library you use has the ability to drop empty clusters. I did a quick search and found that [UMass developed a kmeans](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/api/cc/mallet/cluster/KMeans.html) which does this.

Comment: I haven't tried to run your code (still not knowing how to do that without having Matlab), but where do you make sure that IDX only contains colours from the `new_colors` palette? Won't kmeans calculate a  completely new palette with `max_colors` different colours instead of selecting `max_colours` colours from `new_colors`?

Comment: IDX actually contains references to C, which contains the centroids. And you're right, the centroids in C are different than new_colors. That's why I run the nested for loops. In these for loops, I compare every centroid to every color in new_colors. Whenever I find a closer color in new_color, I update that value into C. To do this I weight the squared deltas of each channel based on the weights suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1720553/3119971). Testing on Lenna, Cameraman, and The Cornell Box seemed to produce reasonable results.

Comment: You are right. But will this work? Let's assume that the input image is a linear grayscale gradient from white to black, the base palette contains four neutral gray tones with the values [0.0, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0] and you are allowed to use two colours. Is it not correct, that the cluster centroids would be computed to 0.25 and 0.75 and that the colours 0.4 and 0.6 would be selected? Considering the requirement to dither the output, these two colours are much less suited to reproduce a decent output than the two other colors 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: Understand that the centroids are not guaranteed to be anywhere in particular. It depends on the image. But I digress. I think I may have misunderstood the question. Are you looking to pass a recolored image into dithering, or are you looking to pass a full colored image into dithering which then dithers using the color palette?

Comment: Please understand that I have no easy way to run your code, that's why I am trying to understand it by parsing it mentally. In my last comment, I defined both the image, palette and number of colours as input values and the output, which I would expect, if I understand your code correctly. Asking you if I have understood it correctly, it does not really help me if you answer "it depends on the image", as I've for this particular case already have described the image.

Comment: Given the theory of kmeans (not my code in particular), 0.25 and 0.75 are not guaranteed. When I ran it on my grayscale image, I got 0.1 and 0.6 as centroids for the selected image. So in that case you were wrong. However, in some other case, it the centroids may be 0.25 and 0.75. So no, you do not understand it correctly because it will vary from image to image. Some greyscale images will have centroids at 0.25 and 0.75, others will not.

Comment: I don't disagree that the centroids will be different from image to image. I described a very particular image (containing nothing but a linear gradient from white to black) and asked if for that image, the centroids 0.25 and 0.75 would be computed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your wording. The example you outlined is indeed a possible case, and those are the results you are seeing. However, I may have also misunderstood your question. So I need some clarification. Where do you intend for the re-coloring to occur? Is this to recolor the image passed to the dithering algorithm, or will the dithering algorithm be using this adjusted palette for it's creation of the image. The kmeans half answers the former, while the nested for loops (I believe) can be used to answer the latter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46790/discussion-between-wbest-and-jarnbjo)

Answer (score 0):

Below is presented an approach implemented in Java using [Marvin Framework](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/). It might be a starting point for solving your problem.

**Input:**

- Palette **P** with **M** colors.
- Number of Colors **N**.
- Image **G**

**Steps:**

1. Apply the Palette **P** to the image **G** by replacing the pixels color to the most similar color (less distance in RGB space) in the palette. The output image has the distribution of palette colors by usage.
2. Compute an histogram containing each color in the palette and how many times it is used in the image (number of pixels).
3. Sort the palette by pixel usage, most to less used.
4. Select the **N** first items in the sorted list and generate a new palette.
5. Apply this new palette to the image.

Below is presented the output of this approach.

**Original image:**

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/other/lena.jpg))</sub>

**Palette, and the image quantitized with 32, 8, 4 colors:**

[image]

**Source code:**

```
public class ColorQuantizationExample {

    public ColorQuantizationExample(){
        MarvinImage imageOriginal = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("./res/quantization/lena.jpg");
        MarvinImage imageOutput = new MarvinImage(imageOriginal.getWidth(), imageOriginal.getHeight());

        Set<Color> palette = loadPalette("./res/quantization/palette_7.png");
        quantitize(imageOriginal, imageOutput, palette, 32);
        MarvinImageIO.saveImage(imageOutput, "./res/quantization/lena_7_32.jpg");

        quantitize(imageOriginal, imageOutput, palette, 8);
        MarvinImageIO.saveImage(imageOutput, "./res/quantization/lena_7_8.jpg");

        quantitize(imageOriginal, imageOutput, palette, 4);
        MarvinImageIO.saveImage(imageOutput, "./res/quantization/lena_7_4.jpg");

        palette = loadPalette("./res/quantization/palette_8.png");
        quantitize(imageOriginal, imageOutput, palette, 32);
        MarvinImageIO.saveImage(imageOutput, "./res/quantization/lena_8_32.jpg");

        quantitize(imageOriginal, imageOutput, palette, 8);
        MarvinImageIO.saveImage(imageOutput, "./res/quantization/lena_8_8.jpg");

        quantitize(imageOriginal, imageOutput, palette, 4);
        MarvinImageIO.saveImage(imageOutput, "./res/quantization/lena_8_4.jpg");
    }

    /**
     * Load a set of colors from a palette image.
     */
    private Set<Color> loadPalette(String path){
        Set<Color> ret = new HashSet<Color>();
        MarvinImage image = MarvinImageIO.loadImage(path);
        String key;
        for(int y=0; y<image.getHeight(); y++){
            for(int x=0; x<image.getWidth(); x++){
                Color c = new Color
                (
                    image.getIntComponent0(x, y),
                    image.getIntComponent1(x, y),
                    image.getIntComponent2(x, y)
                );

                ret.add(c);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private void quantitize(MarvinImage imageIn, MarvinImage imageOut, Set<Color> palette, int colors){
        applyPalette(imageIn, imageOut, palette);
        HashMap<Color, Integer> hist = getColorHistogram(imageOut);


        List<Map.Entry<Color, Integer>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<Color, Integer>>( hist.entrySet() );

        Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Color, Integer>>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare( Map.Entry<Color, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<Color, Integer> o2 )
            {
                return (o1.getValue() > o2.getValue() ? -1: 1);
            }
        } );

        Set<Color> newPalette = reducedPalette(list, colors);
        applyPalette(imageOut.clone(), imageOut, newPalette);
    }

    /**
     * Apply a palette to an image.
     */
    private void applyPalette(MarvinImage imageIn, MarvinImage imageOut, Set<Color> palette){
        Color color;
        for(int y=0; y<imageIn.getHeight(); y++){
            for(int x=0; x<imageIn.getWidth(); x++){
                int red = imageIn.getIntComponent0(x, y);
                int green = imageIn.getIntComponent1(x, y);
                int blue = imageIn.getIntComponent2(x, y);

                color = getNearestColor(red, green, blue, palette);
                imageOut.setIntColor(x, y, 255, color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reduce the palette colors to a given number. The list is sorted by usage.
     */
    private Set<Color> reducedPalette(List<Map.Entry<Color, Integer>> palette, int colors){
        Set<Color> ret = new HashSet<Color>();
        for(int i=0; i<colors; i++){
            ret.add(palette.get(i).getKey());
        }
        return ret;
    }

    /**
     * Compute color histogram
     */
    private HashMap<Color, Integer> getColorHistogram(MarvinImage image){
        HashMap<Color, Integer> ret = new HashMap<Color, Integer>();

        for(int y=0; y<image.getHeight(); y++){
            for(int x=0; x<image.getWidth(); x++){
                Color c = new Color
                (
                    image.getIntComponent0(x, y),
                    image.getIntComponent1(x, y),
                    image.getIntComponent2(x, y)
                );

                if(ret.get(c) == null){
                    ret.put(c, 0);
                }
                ret.put(c, ret.get(c)+1);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private Color getNearestColor(int red, int green, int blue, Set<Color> palette){
        Color nearestColor=null, c;
        double nearestDistance=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        double tempDist;
        Iterator<Color> it = palette.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()){
            c = it.next();
            tempDist = distance(red, green, blue, c.getRed(), c.getGreen(), c.getBlue());
            if(tempDist < nearestDistance){
                nearestDistance = tempDist;
                nearestColor = c;
            }
        }
        return nearestColor;
    }

    private double distance(int r1, int g1, int b1, int r2, int g2, int b2){
        double dist= Math.pow(r1-r2,2) + Math.pow(g1-g2,2) + Math.pow(b1-b2,2);
        return Math.sqrt(dist);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new ColorQuantizationExample();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the issues I commented on wbest's answer apply to this solution as well. Assume an input image with nothing but a white-black gradient, a palette with the gray scales [0.0, 0.33, 0.67, 1.0] and a restriction to use only two colours. Quantizing the image with "nearest selection" from the complete palette would cause the colours 0.33 and 0.67 to be used twice as often as the other two colours and hence be used for further reduction. Also in this case, the colours 0.0 and 1.0 would though have been better suited to render the output image, considering that dithering is used.

Comment: Even if the palette reduction and the dithering can be done in two separate steps, I assume that the palette reduction algorithm at least have to consider *that* dithering is going to take place. The optimum subset is clearly different depending on wether dithering is used or not.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Perhaps, it is necessary to perform dithering in the first step. Analysing the most used color combinations in dithering, compute a histogram of individual colors (or the combinations of them) and quantitize using this new information.